# Kick off an external executable from a Google App Engine background task

Tags: java, google-app-engine, mp4

This question is related to this question: [Calculating length of mp4 video after upload to Google Cloud Storage from GAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18730161/calculating-length-of-mp4-video-after-upload-to-google-cloud-storage-from-gae)

I'm looking to calculate the "duration" of .mp4 files my users upload to my Google App Engine app.  One potential solution I'm investigating is to kick off a background task on file upload that will invoke a third party executable that can parse the metadata of the .mp4 file.

I've found a few mp4 parsers that look up to the task (e.g. http://atomicparsley.sourceforge.net/mpeg-4files.html), but haven't had any luck finding documentation on how to properly kick off a process from within a Google App Engine app.

Is it as simple as uploading the executable to a folder under the WAR directory of my app engine project (Note: My app is written in Java) and invoking it by creating a new Process from a background task?

Would appreciate any advice on this - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently can't kick off external processes in Google App Engine.

You'll have to find a java library to parse the .mp4

There's a new feature which could allow you to do this.  It's in Trusted Tester right now, so you'll have to sign up for that:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/gRZNqlQPKys

You'll basically need to create a VM image with the apps you need to execute.

Comment: Eventually found some threads online where this was mentioned but thanks for the extra confirmation and pointer to the other option!